# Combinatorics - number of terms problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Find the coefficient of ($x^{11} \cdot y \cdot w^8$) in $(x+y+z+w)^{20}$ and find the number of terms in the expansion $(x+y+z+w)^{20}$.

So, the coefficient of ($x^{11} \cdot y \cdot w^8$) in that expression is given by:

$\binom {20} {11}1^{11} \times \binom {9} {1}1^{1} \times \binom {8} {8}1^8=1511640$

However, I don't know how to calculate the number of terms in $(x+y+z+w)^{20}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The terms must all have the form $x^ay^bz^cw^d$ where each of the exponents is non-negative and $a+b+c+d=20$.  Use [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: How did you get that?  Stars and Bars, with $k$ tuples summing to $n$, yields $\binom {n+k-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: @lulu $\binom {23} {3}$ , sorry I was calcuting  for $n=12$ for a similiar exercise

Comment: $\binom {23}3$ is correct.